# "Безусловно" — как определить, какая часть речи?

Tags: вводные-слова, наречия

> Расставьте все недостающие знаки препинания: укажите цифру(-ы), на
> месте которой(-ых) в предложении должна(-ы) стоять запятая(-ые).
>
> Литературная и театральная критика и выступления на теоретические темы
> (1) безусловно (2) занимают в творчестве В. Брюсова значимое место,
> ведь (3) в сущности (4) всё творческое наследие поэта воплощает в себе
> парадоксальное сочетание поэтического таланта и холодного рационализма
> учёного.
>
> Ответ:1234

Почему "безусловно" обособляется знаками препинания? Как различать наречие и вводное слово?

**1.То же, что «конечно, без сомнения». Подробно о пунктуации при вводных словах и сочетаниях см. в Прил. 2.
2.! Не смешивать с употреблением в роли члена предложения (в знач. «безоговорочно, полностью»).**

А разве синонимы у вводного слова и наречия  по значению не близки? Как тогда различать их?

Comment: Интересный вопрос! Вводные слова — это вещь в себе, на этом ресурсе тема часто обсуждалась (правда, без видимых результатов). Жаль только, что "проверяющие" всегда знают правильные ответы, так что надо угадать и угодить. Получается ЛОВУШКА для свободного мышления. Но мне будет любопытно послушать правильные ответы. Кстати, там второе вводное слово также требует к себе внимания (мне так кажется). Но проверяющие и это знают.

Answer (score 2):

*Литературная и театральная критика и выступления на теоретические темы,  **безусловно**, занимают в творчестве В. Брюсова значимое место, ведь, **в сущности**,  всё творческое наследие поэта воплощает в себе парадоксальное сочетание поэтического таланта и холодного рационализма учёного.*

**NEW!**

**1. Здесь два вводных слова**

Кустова называет их **метатекстом**, а мне нравится термин **"маркеры"**, то есть авторские интонационные и смысловые **пометки**. Они произносятся как вставки, не участвуя в построении интонационной структуры предложения в целом.

Запишем предложение **без вводных слов** и разделим его на **синтагмы/такты** (отдельные смысловые и интонационные части **фраз**, удобные для прочтения), а также обозначим фразовое (тоническое) **ударение**:

*Литературная и театральная критика и выступления на теоретические темы/ занимают в творчестве В. Брюсова **знАчимое** место,// ведь (и) всё творческое наследие поэта / воплощает в себе парадоксальное сочетание поэтического таланта / и холодного рационализма **учЁного**.*

Как мы видим, предложение можно прочитать и **без вводных слов**, которые только вносят в него дополнительные смысловые оттенки. (В этом и есть их предназначение.)

Конечно, такой анализ **сложен для школьника** (и доступен только на уровне интуиции). Но, вероятно, авторы рассчитывали на базовые знания, когда вводные слова просто "узнаются" в тексте.

**2. А почему не наречие?**

Если "маркеры" включить в состав предложения, то оптимальная конструкция **нарушается**. Надо смотреть, как эти слова повлияют на структуру предложения.

Например, слово "безусловно" будет находиться в **инверсированной** (ударной) позиции, поэтому его нужно выделить ударением, а зачем?  В то же время "маркер" вполне справляется со своей задачей и подчеркнутого ударения не требует. Да и вся конструкция неоправданно **усложняется**. Зачем лишнее, если есть все нужное? Вводные слова тем и хороши, что это просто **пометки** автора.

Comment: Не совсем ощущаю разницу между ударением и интонацией при вводном слове и наречии... 

Можете привести примеры, где ощущается эта разница? (наречия - вводные слова)

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, пример, где вам трудно определить разницу, я же предложу вам грамматическое и интонационное решение. А в вашем предложении сложно сделать выбор, вам уже писали об этом. С одной стороны, выбор вводных слов предпочтителен, а с другой - наречие тоже может вписаться в структуру этого предложения: Литературная и театральная критика и выступления на теоретические темы / безуслОвно занимают в творчестве В. Брюсова значимое место...  Вы видите подчеркнутое смещение ударения на наречие. А если не смещать, получается монотонное произношение фразы, вариант с вв. словом  лучше.

Comment: ‟авторские интонационные и смысловые пометки” – все вводные произносятся одинаково – с интонацией отступления, здесь нет никаких авторских интонаций. В таком предложении можно удалить слово ‟определённо”: ‟Это определённо вызовет у нас проблемы”, но это не значит, что это вводное. Во всех этих предложениях так же можно удалить утвердительную частицу, и это не делает их вводными: Это определённо вызовет у нас проблемы.
Я действительно не хочу такую работу.
Это несомненно лучшее решение.
Я обязательно решу эту проблему.
Спасение гражданских безусловно является нашей приоритетной целью.

Comment: @Мал  В чем разница между наречием и вводным словом с точки зрения интонации? Наречие – это член предложения, и его надо вписывать в интонационную структуру этого предложения. (Каждое слово влияет на структуру, так что перестройка обязательна!) А вводные слова – свободная конструкция, в общем случае в построении интонационной структуры не участвуют и никак ее не изменяют. Это – свободные маркеры) Отмечу также, что интонационный анализ особенно эффективен для сложных предложений с неоднозначным решением.

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin Любопытно...Но вот  психологи говорят: Чем больше мы с чем-нибудь боремся, тем больше мы его укрепляем. Не знаю, верно ли это?

Comment: Бред? Ну не скажите… Современная наука (в частности, квантовая физика) подтверждают это. Да и наш собственный опыт подсказывает: если мы чего-то опасаемся и часто об этом думаем, то это очень нежелательное почему-то происходит. Как будто мысли получают реальное воплощение.

Comment: @Sharon Можно почитать материалы, откуда вы взяли такую информацию? Хочу поизучать их

Comment: Про то, что интонация, ударение влияет на синтаксис.
*Например, слово "безусловно" будет находиться в инверсированной (ударной) позиции, поэтому его нужно выделить ударением, а зачем? В то же время "маркер" вполне справляется со своей задачей и подчеркнутого ударения не требует. Да и вся конструкция неоправданно усложняется. Зачем лишнее, если есть все нужное? Вводные слова тем и хороши, что это просто пометки автора.*

Comment: А почему всё это нужно откуда-то брать? Как ударение влияет на синтаксис? У каждой синтаксической конструкции есть соответствующая расстановка ударений. Вот и все влияние. Изучайте тему ударений,  я самые  основы брала из вузовского справочника по фонетике. Об интонации сейчас много пишут, ищите походящие для вас  книги, изучайте, сравнивайте. Это большой и долгий труд, между прочим, просто так откуда-то не возьмешь. А ценят эти знания сами видите как.  А ведь других (однозначных) ответов на этот вопрос никто не дал, одна критика.

Comment: Хотите еще один «бред»: «Что наверху — то и внизу».  (Принцип соответствия Гермеса Трисмегиста.) Фраза — это аналог слова. Словесное ударение формирует слово, а фразовое ударение — фразу. Фраза — основной элемент, который  используется для построения предложений разного вида. Хорошо изучить и понять эту тему — значит понять все остальное. Вот с этого и надо начинать.

Comment: Да, "кухня" эта  звучит, вероятно, как речь марсианина. Что ж, пусть даже и так. Зато и награда  того стоит. Вы смотрите на предложение — и вы знаете ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Если можно заменить на **полностью**, то невводное, иначе вводное:

> Литературная и театральная критика и выступления на теоретические темы
> **полностью** занимают в творчестве В. Брюсова значимое место

Но существуют и вводные/наречия неотличимые друг от друга:

> Слова и сочетания слов, которые в функции вводного
> и в другой функции имеют одно и то же значение. Даже по
> контексту невозможно различить, в какой функции употреблено
> то или иное слово: все зависит от желания автора - либо
> подчеркнуть свою субъективность, либо использовать слово
> в свойственной ему функции. Например: **по крайней мере, в
> известном смысле, действительно, между тем, во всяком
> случае, на первый взгляд, так или иначе**.

Comment: У вас семантическое решение, но это не единственный принцип в пунктуации. По грамматике функцию сложно определить, Возможно, надо учитывать структуру и интонацию предложения. Кстати, Грамота.ру иногда говорит о том, что не всегда однозначно решается задача, да и Розенталь об этом тоже говорит. Но это уже не для школы, да и сам вопрос выше школьного уровня.

Comment: Как мне думается, здесь пограничное решение (опять весы, как в теме сравнительного оборота!). Но структура подсказывает, куда оно смещено... Желание автора? Иногда действительно, структура допускает два прочтения по авторскому желанию, но не всегда. К тому же по большому счету мы тогда имеем неоднозначность смысла, а это уже стилистический недочет. (Голос за ответ мой.)

Answer (score 1):

Слово ‟безусловно” может быть много чем – несколькими видами наречий, разными частицами, вводным.

**1. Утвердительная частица.**

Взгляните на выделенные слова в следующих примерах:

Это **определённо** вызовет у нас проблемы.
Я **действительно** не хочу такую работу.
Это **несомненно** лучшее решение.
Я **обязательно** решу эту проблему.
Спасение гражданских **безусловно** является нашей приоритетной целью.

Обычно в книгах с классификациями частиц такие слова относят к подмножеству утвердительных частиц. В утвердительные частицы также входят утвердительные ответы после вопросительных реплик, как в предложениях:

> – Ты пойдёшь в кино?
> – Да.
>
> – Ты пойдёшь в кино?
> – Конечно.

Я бы не стал строить терминологию, смешивая эти слова в один термин, а разделил бы первый вариант на частицы категорического утверждения, а второй – на утвердительные частицы.

Вот примеры предложений с такой частицей:

> Поиск прорывной идеи безусловно является целью гроухакинга, однако стоит понимать, что в большинстве случаев устойчивый продолжительный рост достигается за счёт накопления небольших удачных решений.
>
> Смешанные браки – безусловно важный фактор взаимодействия разных языков и культур.
>
> Отсутствие единства в обучении и боеспособности пехоты в 1806 г. безусловно стали недостатками прусской армии.
>
> Они могут не иметь лоска, но безусловно должны быть профессионалами.

**2. Наречие характеристики действия.**

> Она любила безусловно.
>
> Не менее прочную позицию занимали в его душе немногие истины, добытые путем житейского опыта и безусловно господствовавшие над местностью.
>
> А сейчас давайте попробуем понять, какие причины мешают родителям безусловно принимать ребёнка и показывать ему это.
>
> Проект» ваш я принимаю безусловно и без всяких оговорок.
>
> В прошедшем столетии все ему верили безусловно.
>
> Все выработанные крепостной легальностью ограничения, дававшие подневольному люду возможность вздохнуть, соблюдались им безусловно.
>
> Он впервые узнал власть над женщиной, она предавалась ему безусловно.

**3. Другой вид наречия.** Его можно назвать наречием характеристики характеристики.

> Но самое главное, что объединило этих двух безусловно талантливых военачальников – и тот и другой написали после войны мемуары, в которых высказали практически одни и те же мысли.
>
> Многие из этих более ранних идей нельзя считать безусловно правильными, но они и сейчас имеют большую ценность.
>
> Твоя задача – стать безусловно хорошей инвестицией.
>
> И как так вышло, что спустя год и два после появления всех этих безусловно полезных книг люди почему-то продолжают думать неправильно.
>
> То, что казалось мне безусловно ярким и важным, как-то сразу потускнело, и я понял, что чем невероятнее и чудеснее встреченная в жизни случайность, тем труднее убедительно рассказать о ней…

**4. Вводное.** Я не буду как-то формулировать разницу между вводным и частицей категорического утверждения (а именно с ней могут возникнуть трудности с различением), так как и так потратил на ответ много времени, но приведу несколько примеров. Может быть, они вам помогут. Как минимум разница в произношении будет видна отчётливо.

> Что меня удивило в пленнице: она, безусловно, не была крестьянкой или работницей, но пальцы руки, которой она придерживала у подбородка завязки шапки, были, несомненно, крепки, и самая кисть казалась сильной, хорошо развитой, как рука спортсменки или музыканта…
>
> Безусловно, смертельной была вторая, полученная в грудь.
>
> Взрослый человек по сравнению с мальчиком, безусловно, сильнее, но когда этот взрослый стареет, становится дряхлым, то этот же хлопец уберет его.
>
> Но вы правы, капитан: осторожность требует выяснения источника этих радиопередач. Вы, безусловно, правы, капитан. Больше такой благоприятной ситуации не встретится.

**Ответ:** Сложно сказать, чем является ‟безусловно” в этом предложении. Тут может быть как вводное, так и частица категорического утверждения. Вводное ‟безусловно” – это отступление перед чем-то, что кажется очевидным для автора, а частица категорического утверждения произносится, чтобы убедить человека в чем-то, развеять его сомнения. Нужно знать контекст, и даже в одном контексте возможны, наверное, два варианта. Одно можно сказать наверняка: человека, который создавал этот тест, нужно уволить.

Comment: Я бы не стала настаивать на увольнении составителей теста, но могу отметить, что решение этой задачи не такое простое, как им кажется. Соответственно, для школьного экзамена предложение вряд  ли подходит. Это уже другой уровень анализа.

Comment: Правда, здесь возможен такой вариант: задача рассчитана на базисный уровень знаний. К примеру, я слышала,  что «безусловно» – это вводное слово, поэтому я его обособляю. Но более продвинутые ученики слышали, что у него есть и другие значения. Они начинают сомневаться, «правильное» решение не угадывают и поэтому будут в проигрыше.

Comment: Нет школьного и нешкольного задания, есть качественные и некачественные пособия. Если качественно расписать эту тему, то ни у кого проблем не возникнет. А если некачественно расписать, то проблемы возникнут у всех.